# Understanding a part of the proof of the Invariance of domain from Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

On page number 126 of Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, he has proved invariance of domain.

In the second line of his proof he writes,

> From the long exact sequence for the pair $(\Bbb R^m, \Bbb R^m - \{x\})$ we get $H_k(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \approx \tilde{H}_{k-1}(\Bbb R^m - \{x\}).$

---

But from long exact sequence we have $H_k(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \approx H_{k-1}(\Bbb R^m - \{x\})$ for all $k \gt 0$ and we know that $\tilde{H}_{k-1}(\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \approx H_{k-1}(\Bbb R^m - \{x\})$ for all $k \gt 1$ with $H_0(\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \approx \tilde{H}_0(\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \oplus \Bbb Z$.

So my question is that how does it particularly follow that $H_1(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \approx \tilde{H}_{0}(\Bbb R^m - \{x\})$ ? Am I missing something?

Comment: What you're missing is that either you have to (1) use the appropriate long exact sequence or (2) know what the maps in the long exact sequence actually do -- in essence the extra $\mathbb{Z}$ summands split off as an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long exact sequence for the pair $(A,B)$ with reduced homology is
$$\cdots\to \widetilde{H}_{k+1}(A) \to H_{k+1}(A,B) \to \widetilde{H}_{k}(B) \to \widetilde{H}_{k}(A)\to \cdots$$
which is mentioned on page 118.

Since $A=\mathbb{R}^m$ is contractible, $\widetilde{H}_{k}(A)=0$ for all $k$, hence there are isomorphisms $H_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m-\{x\})\to \widetilde{H}_{k}(\mathbb{R}^m-\{x\})$ for all $k$.

A way to think about what's going on with respect to unreduced homology is that at the end of the sequence
$$\cdots\to H_{1}(A,B) \to H_0(B) \to H_0(A) \to H_0(A,B)\to 0$$
to recall that $H_0$ is measuring the number of connected components.  We have $H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}$ since $A$ has a single connected component.  In the case $m>1$, then $B$ has a single connected component as well, and $H_0(B)\to H_0(A)$ is an isomorphism, and one can deduce that $H_1(A,B)=0$.  In the case $m=1$, then $B$ has two connected components, and the map $H_0(B) \to H_0(A)$ is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$, defined by $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$.  The kernel of this is generated by $(1,-1)$, which is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, and so $H_1(A,B)\approx \mathbb{Z}$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks. But what is wrong with my logic? Is there any subtlety that I have overlooked?

Comment: @Error404 What is your logic?  I only see the assertion that you have an isomorphism when $k>0$, but it should be $k>1$.  $H_0(\mathbb{R}^m)\neq 0$.

Comment: Ah I see!!! I was taking $H_0(\Bbb R^m)=0$. This is so pathetic. Thanks a lot for clarifying this. I wasn't able to sleep because of this.

Comment: @Error404 No problem, glad to help. Hopefully the discussion about what the maps actually do at the end of the LES clarifies things more -- I've found that you actually have to analyze what the maps are doing sometimes, and you can't always just use the sequence as a black box.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn't analyze the maps. I will keep this in mind always!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the [reduced exact sequence for a pair.](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~maxim/751f14w10.pdf)

let $A=\mathbb R^m \setminus \{x\}$

$\tilde H_1(\mathbb R^m) \to H_1(\mathbb R^m,A) \to \tilde{H_0}(A) \to \tilde H_0(\mathbb R^m) \to H_0(\mathbb R^m,A) \to 0$

so in particular, we have

$0 \to H_1(\mathbb R^m,A) \to \tilde H_0(A) \to 0 $

---

Regarding your error, you can apply the usual sequence to get that

$$0 \to H_1(\mathbb R^m,A) \to H_0(A) \to \mathbf Z  \to 0.$$

There are some technical remarks  needed to still get the result, but if you assume some form of splitting, then you get $H_0(A)=H_1(\mathbb R^m,A) \oplus \mathbf Z$,

Comment: Thanks. But can you point out where I went wrong?

Comment: @Error404 I think your last claim is wrong, and in particular, I don't see it.

Comment: By my last claim do you mean $H_0(\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \approx \tilde{H}_0(\Bbb R^m - \{x\}) \oplus \Bbb Z$ ? If yes, then Hatcher says that $H_0(X) \approx \widetilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$ for any topological space $X$.

Comment: Sorry! First claim I thought that your confusion was about the very end of the sequence. I wrote out k=1

Comment: My first claim is precisely $\textbf{Corollary 1}$ in the PDF provided by you. Yes you are right my confusion is about $k=1$ only.

Comment: No it is not. Just write out the sequence at k=1.  There is no evident isomorphism

Comment: @AndresMejia $H_0(\mathbb{R}^m,A)=0$, not $\mathbb{Z}$, since $A$ contains a point in every connected component of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @KyleMiller ha my bad, I was editing on my phone and this was turning into a disaster.

Comment: @AndresMejia No problem. By the way, a technical condition why the short exact sequence splits is that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module (so is a "projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module").

Comment: @KyleMiller that sounds right, but I guess you just have to argue that it is torsion free, which is clear, but I guess inessential to the main thrust of this argument with relative homology. Why did you put projective in quotation marks?

Comment: @AndresMejia It's in quotes because you don't really need the theory of projective modules to see that any short exact sequence ending in $\cdots\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ splits.